# Download a page using bash which requires authentication

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I know this has been asked several times before but the solutions didnt work for me.
I'm using ubuntu 14 TLS and i want to download a certain page on an external appliance and save it as html file.
The problems:

1. To get to the page a need to enter a username and password on a login page. As far as i know the authentication works over JavaScript.
2. The page i want to download is something like a database. And to see the information i want to save i have to click a "show all" button on that page which also uses JavaScript.

I've tried

```
wget --secure-protocol=TLSv1 --user=op --password=pw --save-cookies cookies.txt --no-check-certificate https://10.84.163.146/login/login

wget --load-cookies cookies.txt -p https://10.84.163.146/analyses.
```

but it doesnt work.

Also i tried

```
wget --cookies=on --save-cookies=cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate  --post-data 'user=op&passwort=pw' https://10.84.163.146/

wget --cookies=on --load-cookies=cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate https://10.84.163.146/analyses
```

It downloads a file but its always the Login Page.
The cookie.txt contains following information:

```
# HTTP cookie file.
# Generated by Wget on 2015-08-24 15:29:10.
# Edit at your own risk.

10.84.163.146   FALSE   /   TRUE    0   BALANCEID   balancer.thin1
10.84.163.146   FALSE   /   TRUE    0   _session_id dcfd63dad96cede4c3e5927335cbf411
```

This is the login script:

```
// Make sure we have cookies enabled for this site
var tmpcookie = new Date();
chkcookie = (tmpcookie.getTime() + '');
document.cookie = "chkcookie=" + chkcookie + "; path=/";
if (document.cookie.indexOf(chkcookie,0) < 0) {
   alert("Cookies are required for this site.\n" +
    "Please unblock cookies in your browser setting.");
 }

 (function($){
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#login-container').find('input.form-control').blur(function(e){
       $('#login-container').find('.form-group.auth').removeClass('focus');
}).focus(function(e){
  $(this).parents('.form-group:first').addClass('focus');
    });
   });
 })(jQuery);
```

And ideas?

Comment: Similar command with --post-data works for me.     wget --save-cookies cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate  --post-data 'user=op&passwort=pw' https://10.84.163.146/

Comment: Just tried it, doesnt work for me.

Comment: What does the javascript do? It's essential to the solution to know how the application operates. If Javascript is, for example, only used to do an XHR to retrieve the data, you should simply fetch that URL. If it does some kind of handshake with the backend, you will need to know what that entails... etc.

Comment: @GerardvanHelden added the script in the Post above

Comment: If that javascript is executed on the client side then wget isn't going to work. wget doesn't execute javascript.

Comment: wget was just an approach to try it. feel free to suggest other options. I would try everything as long as its possible to work over CLI

Comment: You may want to check out PhantomJS for this (http://phantomjs.org/). You can write PhantomJS script to do browserless client-side javascript whatnots. Unfortunately there is not slam dunk solution like wget is for HTML.

Comment: okay. thank you, time to learn Java Script now i guess

Comment: try adding &NEXTURL=/<nextpage> to --post-data

Comment: @MaheshKharvi doesnt work either

Comment: Have you tried using curl instead of wget?  Just a thought, you may have more control.

Comment: Try logging in to the server using a regular browser like Chrome, and look at the "Network" tab in Developer Tools.  That will give you details of the interaction that happens with the server and allow you to duplicate it independently.

Answer (score 0):

### Why your attempt might not work:

The login script you mention is javascript code that should run in a browser as a pre-check to presenting the file for download.
Since you are running from wget, it shouldn't be able to download jQuery sources from a CDN, execute the different modules, turn on whatever flags are needed and and finally let the browser present the download dialog.
In this case, it should be a client-side validation, but from the looks of it, but we are talking about an excerpt so we are tied to wondering and making assumptions.

### Some tasks to follow that may guide you in the right direction:

Your best bet, is to install somethng that actually let's you see what is going on and where the browser is downloading the data from.

- If Firefox, you can use Live HTTP Headers to see what is the actual file link you desire, be careful, it is very verbose but that also means it give you a lot of control.
- If Chrome, you might want to try with its own set of tools, just press F2 and be vigilant on the Network tab.

It might be possible the download link have extra parameters that you may tweak from your bash script, these tools should let you see them and act accordingly :)